# Python: tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "label" command: application has been destroyed

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

When i exit the tk window i get this long library error, and I have no idea how to fix it. the GUI itself and error message are below the code.

```
def golf_records()->None:
  """
  This function prints the information
  of golfer names and the score they have 
  """
  with open("golf.txt", "r") as myfile:
    myfile_content = myfile.read()
    GUI_print(myfile_content)

def GUI_print(data)->None:
  """
  The function takes in a string found in golf.txt file
  and prints it out through tkinter GUI
  """
  my_label = Label(root,text = str(data),font=("ariel",15)).place(x=250,y=120)
  

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")

#Lables
header = Label(root,text = "Current Golf Records",font=("ariel",15,"bold")).place(x=150,y=20)
header = Label(root,text = "-----------------------------",font=("ariel",15)).place(x=150,y=50)
header = Label(root,text = "Press enter to list players data: ",font=("ariel",15)).place(x=150,y=80)

#Buttons
enter = Button(root, text="Enter", activebackground = "green", command=golf_records).place(x=440,y=80)


root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  golf_records()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your function `golf_records()` is only executed after the `mainloop()` ends, ie, after you exit the window. Hence the application is destroyed and then the function is run, which shows a label, but cannot, as the application is destroyed. Hence the error

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH MAN! my python professor is horrible, she spent 5 minutes looking at it and told me that I am on my own. Also just to clarify, after I hit exit, why does idle decide to re-run the code again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically imagine like your code is executed till the `mainloop()` and it pauses there till you break out of the loop, ie, by exiting the application. Then the code after the `mainloop()` gets executed, ie, the `if` statements which is true, hence running the function `golf_record()` which calls the `GUI_print()` which activates the label.

How to solve this? Im not sure what your trying to do with this code here, but if you can move that `root.mainloop()` to the end of the `if` statement, itll execute the function while the code is initially executed. Do let me know if you have more doubts. Or the better way would be to get rid of the function call `golf_records()` inside the `if` because you have a button that calls the function anyway.

Comment: Wow, I was so confused about this but it is much clearer now. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out. I just got rid of the golf_records() function in the if __name__ statement and it works perfectly :)